# Double Maths Random in Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I need your help because I'm totally lost with a javascript exercise (I learn alone).

I cut the exercice in steps

1. I generate an aleatory number between 3 and 20 (with Maths Random)
2. I generate an array of 100 cells: In each cells, there is one " _ "
3. If the number is 5: 5 " _ " is aleatory replaced by a " # " (second Maths Random)

I think my cut is good but I can't write it in code.
Before this exercise I've done exercises easier with maths random but now it's more diffult for me.

Some can help me to create the code?

Thank you very much

edit: I tried to do something but without maths random.

```
function hashtagLine(){

    var number = prompt( "Saisissez un nombre entre 3 et 10" );
    var line = "";

    if (number >= 1 && number <= 10){

        for ( var i = 1; i <= 100; i++ ) {

            if ( i % number === 0 ) {

                line += "#";

            } else {

                line += "_";
            }
        }

        console.log( line );

    } else {

        alert( "vous avez entré un nombre qui ne correspond pas" );

    }
}

hashtagLine();
```

Comment: You should still try writing some code, then we can help correcting it.

Comment: so you want us to give the implementation for all the 3 steps? or just a particular part?

Comment: I want to give the implementation for all 3 steps.

Comment: I'm trying to code it but it's still complex for me

Comment: Show us what you have and then we could be of help.

Comment: I edit my message, you can see what i've done but there is no maths random

Comment: So where are you stuck using `Math.random()`?

Comment: What do you mean by `3. If the number is 5: 5 "_" is aleatory replaced by a "#" (second Maths Random)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation:

HTML

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

JS

```
var t = document.getElementById('table');
var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 17 + 3);
var string = '<tr>';

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i == rnd) {
        string += '<td>#</td>';
    } else {
        string += '<td>_</td>';
    }
    // for new row...
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        string += '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
string += '</tr>';
t.innerHTML = string;
```

But if you're trying to learn the language, it's best to try yourself, not just have somebody hand you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but here is some code that may help you. If you come back with more information then I may be able to help you some more.

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```js
// get reference to out output element
var pre = document.getElementById('out');

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function hashtagLine() {
    var min = 3,
        max = 20,
        cells = 100,
        number = getRandomInt(min, max + 1),
        line = [],
        index;

    // create the line array of length cells
    for (index = 0; index < cells; index += 1) {
        // unclear what you are trying to do here!
        if (index % number === 0) {
            line.push('#');
        } else {
            line.push('_');
        }
    }

    // output the array as a line of text
    pre.textContent += line.join('') + '\n';
}

// Add a click event listener to our generate button
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', hashtagLine, false);
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```